# Are there SEO repercussions of using ::before selector to add content to the page?

Tags: seo, css, content

I'm working on a website where I don't have full access to the code.
I'm having to use a `::before` content selector to add a sub-header.

Are there any known SEO repercussions from doing this? Specifically from Google thinking it is some black hat shenanigans.

I'm not too worried if the search engines aren't actually able to crawl the text as it isn't too important from an SEO perspective. But I don't want Google thinking I'm being sneaky and trying to inject some keywords or something.

Comment: I removed the term "negative SEO" from this post because negative SEO is the blackhat practice of intentionally harming the SEO of another site.   Doing something on your own site that might hurt your own SEO would not be considered "negative SEO"